# add text in multipule files recursivly in a spicific line

Tags: command-line, bash, shell-script

I want to add {% load static %} to the second line in all the html files in the directory

this is my folder structure.

```
 ├── fullstack
│   └── index.html
├── git
│   ├── 1.html
│   ├── 2.html
│   ├── 3.html
│   ├── 4.html
│   ├── 5.html
│   └── git.html
├── home.html
├── html_css
│   ├── 10.html
│   ├── 11.html
│   ├── 12.html
│   ├── 13.html
│   ├── 14.html
│   ├── 15.html
│   ├── 1.html
│   ├── 2.html
│   ├── 3.html
│   ├── 4.html
│   ├── 5.html
│   ├── 6.html
│   ├── 7.html
│   ├── 8.html
│   ├── 9.html
│   └── html-css.html
├── javascript
│   ├── 10.html
│   ├── 11.html
│   ├── 12.html
│   ├── 13.html
│   ├── 14.html
│   ├── 15.html
│   ├── 16.html
│   ├── 1.html
│   ├── 2.html
│   ├── 3.html
│   ├── 4.html
│   ├── 5.html
│   ├── 6.html
│   ├── 7.html
│   ├── 8.html
│   ├── 9.html
│   └── javascript.html
└── projects
    ├── facebook_project
    │   ├── 10.html
    │   ├── 11.html
    │   ├── 12.html
    │   ├── 13.html
    │   ├── 14.html
    │   ├── 15.html
    │   ├── 1.html
    │   ├── 2.html
    │   ├── 3.html
    │   ├── 4.html
    │   ├── 5.html
    │   ├── 6.html
    │   ├── 7.html
    │   ├── 8.html
    │   ├── 9.html
    │   └── facebook-project.html
    ├── one_mac_project
    │   ├── 10.html
    │   ├── 11.html
    │   ├── 1.html
    │   ├── 2.html
    │   ├── 3.html
    │   ├── 4.html
    │   ├── 5.html
    │   ├── 6.html
    │   ├── 7.html
    │   ├── 8.html
    │   ├── 9.html
    │   └── one-mac-project.html
    └── projects.html
```

Answer (score 1):

This is a common FAQ.

```
find . -type f -name '*.html' -exec sed -i '2s/^/{% load static %}/' {} \;
```

Not all `sed` variants support `-i` and some (notably *BSD, including MacOS) require an empty argument to the option, like `sed -i '' '2s/...`

The address expression `2` matches the second line and the regular expression `^` matches the beginning of line; so we are saying "replace (the empty string at the) beginning of line with this text on line 2".

I am obviously interpreting "add to the second line" as inserting this static new text before the existing contents of the line.  There are other operations you could perform, such as inserting a new line, or replacing the existing contents, or inserting the new static text after the current contents of the line.  All of these are easy to do with `sed`, but the syntax can be slightly different on different platforms.

If you don't have `sed -i` at all then maybe look into using Perl instead.

```
find ... -exec perl -i -pe 's/^/{% load static %}/ if $. == 2; $. = 0 if eof' {} +
```

In so many words `find ... -exec x {} +` says to execute `x` on all the files which match the predicates in `...`.  The difference between `+` and `\;` is that the former will run as few instances as possible; so

```
x foundfile1.html path/to/foundfile2.html another/foundfile3.html ...
```

whereas with `\;` you run one instance for each file:

```
x foundfile1.html
x path/to/foundfile2.html
x another/foundfile3.html
:
```

which is obviously a lot less efficient.  With the Perl variant, I specifically rigged the script so that it keeps track of the line number for each input file separately, so you can use this more efficient syntax (provided your `find` version supports it); whereas with `sed` the address 2 only matches the second line in the entire sequence of files, and so we are forced to execute one instance of this script per file anyway.